# Does the subset of automorphisms constitute a vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given an arbitrary vector space $(V,+_V,\bullet_V)$ over the field $K$.
One can construct a set of all linear maps:
\begin{align}
End(V) := Hom(V,V) = \{\phi:V \xrightarrow{\sim} V \}
\end{align}
and equip it with the operations: 
\begin{align}
+_{H}:&Hom(V,V)\times Hom(V,V) \to Hom(V,V) \\
*_{H}:&K \times Hom(V,V) \to Hom(V,V) \\
\end{align} 
 so it can also constitute a vector space $(Hom(V,V),+_{H},*_{H})$.
Does the subset of invertible linear maps:
\begin{align}
 Aut(V):=\{\phi:V \xrightarrow{\sim} V \,\,|\,\, \exists\phi^{-1}  \}\subseteq Hom(V,V) 
\end{align}
constitute a vector subspace $(Aut(V),+_H, *_H)$ with respect to given operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because id doesn't contain the zero map $V\to V$, which is the neutral element of the addition in $End(V)$ (assuming $\dim V>0$).

Answer (score 2):

No, since the identity $i \in \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ is invertible, but $i - i = 0$ is not.